# expression "value%2" and "value%2 != 0", which is more efficient

Tags: c, if-statement

```
int value;
```

1. `if (value % 2) {...}`
2. `if (value % 2 != 0) {...}`

I do know the second is more easily readable, but which one is more efficient in C, 1 or 2? And why?

Comment: I find the first as readable as the second, but I guess that's a question of habit

Comment: If you want efficiency, compile your codes with optimizing compiler. Nothing to do with style.

Comment: They mean the same thing. They are compiled to the same thing. You can start by reading the assembly generated by optimizing compilers for various programs, it will help you understand how nonsensical your question is.

Comment: @Morb: Yeah, but I do prefer the second style without efficiency loss. Thx.

Comment: Why are people close-voting this as opinion based? There's nothing opinion-based about which one is most efficient.

Comment: @Lundin: You mean theoretically or experimentally? And without much efficiency difference, people want to know which form is better in programming practice.

Comment: @kingo Well, they are both 100% equivalent in terms of the C standard and in reality. The compiler will translate them to the very same thing early on in the compilation phase, and they will therefore always generate the very same machine code.

Comment: @kingo What's most readable might be a bit subjective, so I would do like another user recommended, follow the MISRA rules, which only allows the latter form. MISRA (2012 rule 14.4) enforces control expressions to be "essentially boolean". Meaning that since != yields a type which would have been boolean, if only C had a sane bool system, it should be used, as the intention is clear and readable. 1) on the other hand yields an int. By using a static code analysis tool and following that MISRA rule, you enforce a stronger typing than C actually has.

Comment: 1. is bad because of situations such as for example: `char* ptr;` Then `if(ptr)` vs `if(*ptr)`. We can see what the code does, but we don't know the programmer's intention. Check against null? Check against zero? Check for null termination of a string? As since we don't know that, we can't spot any potential bugs. On the other hand, with explicit code like `if(ptr == NULL)`, `if(*ptr == 0)`, `if(*ptr == '\0')`, the programmer's intention is perfectly clear.

Comment: I agree with @Lundin this is not opinion based. The question is about the performance difference, not what's most readable. In this the standard is quite clear.

Comment: @Lundin I voted to close as “too broad”, which I felt was the closest approximation to “This question shows a deep misunderstanding and doesn't make sense, just like ‘Since fishes are mammals, why don't they have hooves?’. One could write tons of ‘which is faster between this construct and this trivially equivalent construct in C?’, and none of them would improve this site.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Huh? It is a very narrow question. The question is open-ended, the correct answer is simply "there is no performance difference". If the OP already knew this, they wouldn't be asking. Come on, there is no need to close this question at all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are the exact same. Any condition in an if statement is tested wether it is true (non-zero) or false (zero), so even if you don't write out the test against zero the generated code does that test for you.

From the C11 standard:

> **6.8.4.1 The if statement:**
>
> [...]In both forms, the first substatement is executed if the expression compares unequal to 0.

Edit: You can also verify this for your compiler by looking at the generated code. In my case (GCC 2.4.9) both of the forms produce this code:

```
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax  ; Load `value` into eax
    andl    $1, %eax        ; % 2 (same as & 1)
    testl   %eax, %eax      ; is it zero?
    je  .L2                 ; yes, jump
```

I compiled with no optimization (-O0), just to get that out of the way.

Answer (score -4):

The first is in view of performance (depending on compiler, because it is suggestable that any known compiler would be able to detect and optimize it anyway) the better one as the second one simply executes an additional comparrison.

Comment: I know I'm not wrong, so I would like to get a statement why downvoted?

Comment: Not mine downvote, but C does not define the cost of operations, so "additional comparison performance" is pointless statement, unless you explicitly state source-to-cpucode conversion rules.

Comment: @user3125367: True point. But anyway I would say it is in generall valid that the first won't be slower then the second at all.

Comment: The question is too broad without specifying the compiler, version and optimization flags. In fact, both expressions are equivalent for any modern compiler.

Comment: @user3125367: Thats what I tried to clarify with the side note too.

Comment: But you are wrong. Either form will get translated into one single "branch if zero"/"branch if not zero" assembler instruction on any compiler I have ever seen. Optimization and "modern compilers" has nothing to do with it. Ever since ancient times, CPUs have had such an instruction, and it is the only instruction that the compiler can sensibly translate this C code into, regardless of optimization. There will be no additional comparison, it wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: @Lundin Straightforward compiler (or interpreter) implementation could make two branches – first for explicit comparison, second for if-expr value. Thus "modern compilers" and "optimization" have something to do with it definitely in terms of performance. You can't tell how many comparisons will be there without defining exact compilation algorythms.

Comment: @Lundin E.g. Intel cpus can even branch directly on if(a-b), as sub reg,reg already yields zero flag, or may not branch at all, if entire if-body can be compiled as cmov or sete.

Comment: @user3125367 The number of branches will not be different between 1. and 2, nor will the machine code. So I'm really not sure what you are trying to say.

Comment: That's because we still have not defined conversion rules, @Lundin.